# React Native or Swift gzip unpack to Documents directory on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, gzip, react-native-fs

I have a React Native app that needs to decompress a gzip file so that it can access the individual files that are inside the gzip file. Exactly like how it works when you tap on the file in the iOS Files app and it extracts everything into a folder in the same directory. I can read the gzip using RNFS but that is just a stream of the raw data. I need the actual files that have been zipped up.

I could also do this in native Swift but I don't see a way to do it. NSData has a `decompress()` func but that's also just raw data. It must be possible, any thoughts?

I tried react-native-zip-archive `unzip(base64DecodedString, filePath)` but it doesn't seem to support gzip.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't save the decompressed data to a file after you have decompressed the gzip file into memory?

Comment: @weyhan I haven't had any luck yet with using FNFS.write and the decompressed data (base64 decoded)

Comment: I see the confusion. gzip file decompress into one single file. If you have a gzip file that contains multiple files, the files are combined with another format usually `tar`, before gzip compresses the combined package into the gzip file you are trying to unpack. So, you need to figure out what is the package used to combine the files and find an API that can unpack all the files into individual files. Hope that helps.

Comment: @weyhan yea it's tar but I left that out for simplicity sake - file ends with `tar.gz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in Swift - you need both Gzip and Light-Swift-Untar Swift packages:

```
// JSON with base64 value which represents the tar.gz
if let type = resultDict["resultsData"] as? String {
  // create Data from the base64 string
  if let gzipData = Data(base64Encoded: type, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
    // check if isGzipped, from Gzip Swift pkg
    if gzipData.isGzipped {
        let ddata = NSData(base64Encoded: type)
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/unpacked.tar"
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        do{
          // first decompress gzip and write the tar file, using Gzip Swift pkg
          try! gzipData.gunzipped().write(to: url, options: .atomic)
          // next use the Light-Swift-Untar FileManager extension to unarchive the tar
          try FileManager.default.createFilesAndDirectories(path: "\(documentsPath)/exxxtracted", tarPath: filePath)
        } catch let failedError {
          print("Failed to write the gzip data due to \(failedError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
  }
}
```